# Add multiple selects in one dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the dataset below and in it I consolidate the categories Mk_Cap, Exports and Money_Supply, but each of these grids has a different Unit.

```
 df <- data.frame(Mes=c("Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai",
               "Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai",
               "Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai"),
         Ano=c(2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,
               2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,
               2005,2006,2007,2008,2009),
         Mk_Cap=c(11:15,116:120,1111:1115), 
         Exports=c(21:25,146:150,1351:1355),
         Money_Supply=c(31:35,546:550,2111:2115),
         Unit=c("USD","USD","USD","USD","USD","200=10",
                "200=10","200=10","200=10","200=10",
                "CNY","CNY","CNY","CNY","CNY"))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6VDx.png)

Today I am consolidating as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
Money_Supply <- df %>% dplyr::select(Ano, Mes,Money_Supply) %>% dplyr::filter(df$Unit == "USD")
Mk_Cap <- df %>% dplyr::select(Mk_Cap) %>% dplyr::filter(df$Unit == "200=10")
Exports <- df %>% dplyr::select(Exports) %>% dplyr::filter(df$Unit == "CNY")

Consolidado <- base::cbind(Money_Supply,Mk_Cap,Exports)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwqNJ.png)

I believe that it is not the most correct way to do this, but today it is the way that I found, in this example that I passed there are few occurrences, but in the practical case I do this in more than 30 variables which is extremely costly, if there is any way easier would be ideal.

Comment: The `cbind` only works when the datasets have the same number of rows.  Your code is filtering on different values..  It is not clear why you wanted to do this way

Comment: What do you mean by "consolidate"?

Comment: Also, it seems like a group by operation i.e. `df %>% group_split(Unit) %>% map2(list(c("Ano", "Mes", "Money_Supply"), "Mk_Cap", "Exports"), ~ .x %>% select(.y))`

Comment: @akrun your solution does not return what the OP wanted.

Comment: @eduardokapp It returns a `list` and the reason I specified about `cbind` applies here.  The OP's code with `cbind` only worked because of the data.  It would not work in other cases

Comment: @akrun you're right about the correct structure (using a `list` instead of using `cbind`). However, note that the OP does not exactly perform a group_by operation. He arbitrarily selects the values for each variable based on the `Unit` column. It only works because there are 5 rows for every unique value in `Unit`. Your code, however, selects the wrong units for each variable. Pretty confusing, I know, but run his code and your code and see for yourself.

Comment: @eduardokapp There are only 3 unique elements in 'Unit' and by splitting, it returns a list of data.frame.  then in `map2`, I am passing the `list` of column names in the same order as he showed in the post.  May be I am wrong

Comment: I would like to know if I would be able to do the output shown above but without having to do several variable assignments, I would like to do it in a more readable way, I don't know if I would have that possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with dplyr:
There is a pattern in the dataframe. Each year has three rows.
Of the three column of interest `Money_Supply, Mk_Cap, Exports` each variable is in the first, second or third row.
First reorder the columns, then arrange by year, then lead the columns of interest. Then group and filter by `id==1`.

```
df1 <- df %>%
  select(Ano, Mes, Money_Supply, Mk_Cap, Exports) %>% 
  arrange(Ano) %>% 
  mutate(Mk_Cap = lead(Mk_Cap, order_by = Ano)) %>% 
  mutate(Exports = lead(Exports, 2, order_by = Ano)) %>% 
  mutate(group = rep(row_number(), each=3, length.out = n())) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(id ==1) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-group, -id)
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(Mes=c("Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai",
                       "Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai",
                       "Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai"),
                 Ano=c(2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,
                       2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,
                       2005,2006,2007,2008,2009),
                 Mk_Cap=c(11:15,116:120,1111:1115), 
                 Exports=c(21:25,146:150,1351:1355),
                 Money_Supply=c(31:35,546:550,2111:2115),
                 Unit=c("USD","USD","USD","USD","USD","200=10",
                        "200=10","200=10","200=10","200=10",
                        "CNY","CNY","CNY","CNY","CNY"))
```

**Edit: Try to clarify my point and the simplicity of the pattern in the data:**

```
# slightly simplified code
df1 <- df %>% 
  arrange(Ano) %>% 
  mutate(Mk_Cap = lead(Mk_Cap, order_by = Ano)) %>% 
  mutate(Exports = lead(Exports, 2, order_by = Ano)) %>% 
  group_by(Ano) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(id ==1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Ano, Mes, Money_Supply, Mk_Cap, Exports, -id, -Unit)
```

If you consider your dataframe like Fig1 with `arrange(Ano)`:
[image]

1. You have 5 `Ano` (orange): 2005-2009
2. In each `Ano` you have 1 `Mes`(purple): In 2005 = Jan, 2006 = Fev, 2007 = Mar, 2008 = Abr, 2009 = Mai
3. In each `Ano` and `Mes` you have 3 `Unit` (blue): In 2005 & Jan = USD, 200=10, CNY ; In 2006 & Fev = USD, 200=10, CNY ; etc...

**In your desired output you wish to have:**

to condense the
3 rows of one `Ano` with 3 different `Unit` to
1 row with `Ano`, `Mes` and the corresponding values of `Money_Supply, Mk_Cap, Exports`

**This can be achieved by `lead` function (see Fig.1):**

1. In `Money_Supply`: no code necessary is already in the first row (color green)
2. In `Mk_Cap`: `mutate(Mk_Cap = lead(Mk_Cap, order_by = Ano))` yellow arrow
3. In `Exports`: `mutate(Exports = lead(Exports, 2, order_by = Ano))` red arrow
4. `group_by(Ano)`             Group by `Ano`
5. `mutate(id = row_number())` Assign unique `id` within each group
6. `filter(id ==1)`        Filter the 1 row in each group
7. Finally tweak the order of columns and remove unnesseccary columns.
   `select(Ano, Mes, Money_Supply, Mk_Cap, Exports, -id, -Unit)`

[image]

Comment: It took me more than 30 minutes to create the code above. When there is an issue with my answer and down voting is indicated. Please leave a short comment in order to improve myself. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your answer may be correct, but it may not be as simple or as readable as the OP wanted. However, this is an opinionated issue left to the OP.

Comment: Thank you eduardokapp. I appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple way would be filtering your dataset by the `Unit` column before doing any other operations. Store the variations in a list by performing:

```
unit_variations <- lapply(unique(df$Unit), function(x) {
    return(df[df$Unit == x, ])
})
names(unit_variations) <- unique(df$Unit)
```

Then, to make your `Consolidado` dataframe, select which variables you want from which unit variations. Say:

```
vars <- c("Money_Supply", "Mk_Cap", "Exports")
unit <- c("USD", "200=10", "CNY")

Consolidado <- mapply(
    FUN = function(var, unit) {
        return(unit_variations[[unit]][[var]])
    },
    vars,
    unit
)
```

I used a list because, from what you described, I cannot assume that the number of rows for each type of `Unit` will always be the same, so a list allows for more flexibility. I also did not include month and year, for the same reason.